# Akka Http map response on rejection discarded

Tags: scala, akka-http

I currently do a logging operation using mapResponse, as well as utilise the setCookie directive to perform a token rotation.  However when a reject is called it disregards all previous mapResponse calls.  Is there a way for this not to happen?

Here is a super simple illustrative example where the set cookie is dropped:

```
  get{
    setCookie(HttpCookie("Test", "Value")) {
      reject(MalformedRequestContentRejection("Bad content", new Exception("Pants")))
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So one confusing thing about akka-http is there's 3 possible ways a route can be completed. Either `Complete(httpResonse)`, `Reject(rejection)` or with an exception. `mapResponse` only maps in the `Complete` case.

You can use `handleRejections` or `handleException` to convert Rejections/Exceptions into a Complete with a Response.

If you don't, the framework will use its default mappers, which is happening after all your directives have already finished (too late for your `mapResponse` call).

Have your `mapResponse` directive *outside* of `handleExceptions`/`handleRejections` so that you will be dealing with a Response object, and not exceptions/rejections reasons.

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._

mapResponse(loggingMethodHere) {
  handleExceptions(exceptionHandler) {
    handleRejections(rejectionHandler) {
      complete("your logic here")
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if you're not worried about catching Exceptions, you can use `mapRouteResult` to handle the `Complete` and the `Rejected` cases.

```
mapRouteResult {
    case Complete(response) =>
      log.info(s"Logging responses $response")
      Complete(response)
    case Rejected(rejects) =>
      log.info(s"route rejected with $rejects")
      Rejected(rejects)
  }
```